# Image inside HTML <img> tag has wrong width (not corresponding to the one from its css)

Tags: html, css, image

I have a really strange problem, may be i don't understand or not able to see something obvious, but in my opinion really strange things happen.

I have a list  of elements, each of them has a child  tag which has static 80px width set inside its css class. Sometimes, random of those images are loaded like this (screenshot):

https://res.cloudinary.com/leninsdo/image/upload/v1562003304/Screenshot_2_thnczb.png

They have a width 35px and some margin instead of having 80px width as they expected to be and as most of them are in most cases. And this is really random, happens from time to time, cannot even debug this in any way.

But what is more intresting to me, when I click "Select an element in the page to inspect it" in the chrome inspector:

https://res.cloudinary.com/leninsdo/image/upload/v1562003333/Screenshot_3_sk0zrz.png

All images immediately resize to normal 80px as they expected to be:

https://res.cloudinary.com/leninsdo/image/upload/v1562003588/Screenshot_4_wp5d7m.png

Why this can happen?

---

**UPDATE**

The code exact excerpt from source code, which you asked for:

```
<div className="doc-attachment">
    <img src={attach.imageSrc} />
    <div>
        <div>{attach.name}</div>
        <div>{"Дата загрузки: " + getFormattedDate(attach.date)}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.doc-attachment img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a `@media query` is adjusting some parent element and the Inspctor running changes the screen space size reducing it and so avoiding the media query that effects your `img` element.

Comment: Please show your relevant HTML and CSS code on the question. Thank.

Comment: @Martin it's all on screenshots, attached as links to the questions

Comment: @Martin no, all media queries are run when page loaded, i've checked that

Comment: Ok. Check your site.css line which shows that `height: 100%` . Also; your image is loading a 1280 x 659px file to display an 80x80 thumbnail. that's deeply inefficient `;-)`

Comment: @ОлегРубин Since when can you check the code from a screenshot.?.. We obviously need more than that, it's an intricate problem

Comment: @Tofandel OK, added sources, hope this will help. But the bug and what exactly I cannot understand why all is ok after i click the button in inspector. This is really weird from my point of view and it, as i understand, does not depend on sources

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: It's still not enough, we need access to code of ancestors, full js etc, that's obviously where the problem comes from, you will never be able to reproduce your bug with the code you provided
If you don't want to give the url of the project then make a snippet **reproducing the bug**

Comment: > Note that the <img> tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has. – Rob yesterday

@Rob This is jsx